# what is correlation of two vectors of 0

Tags: correlation

what is correlation of two vectors of 0?

A:
000000000000000
B:
000000000000000

The R cor function gives NA result, but is the correlation 1 or that it is undefined? However, in my model, 0 output is clearly a legitimate output.

Comment: What would the correlation between two zero vectors even mean?  You say it's a legitimate output, but I don't see how it could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your vectors have no variance, so correlation is undefined.